# VBA Shorten Code to less than 255 Char

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to transpose some arrays, but have some that have characters longer than 255 that give me trouble.  So, I wanted to see if someone could help me shorten this code below.

My data has a column of flagged (1 or 0) and amount (amt).  What the formula does is looks at my flagged column and finds 3 1's that are on the same row as my formula or above, but only looking up no more than 11 rows.  Then, once it finds three 1's in the flagged column it averages the 3 corresponding amt's.

```
IFERROR(IF(RC[-2]=1, AVERAGE(INDEX(R[-11]C[-1]:RC[-1], MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,R[-11]C[-2]:RC[-2])))), INDEX(R[-11]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1],MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,R[-11]C[-2]:R[-1]C[-2])))), INDEX(R[-11]C[-1]:R[-2]C[-1],MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,OFFSET(R[-2]C[-2],-9,0,MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,R[-11]C[-2]:R[-1]C[-2])))-1)))))),0),0)
```

Assume this data continues on for more than 12 entries...

```
flag | amt | avg
  1  |  5  |  0
  1  |  6  |  0
  1  |  2  |  4.33 = (2+6+5)/3
  0  |  7  |  0
  1  |  6  |  4.67 = (6+2+6)/3
  1  |  11 |  6.33 = (11+6+2)/3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This R1C1 based formula is only 162 characters, and it is not an array formula so:

```
Range("C2:C7").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC1<>0,AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(C2:C2,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(R1C1:RC1)/(R1C1:RC1=1),3)):RC2,INDEX(C1:C1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(R1C1:RC1)/(R1C1:RC1=1),3)):RC1,1),0),0)"
```

[image]

---

So to  limit the number of rows we need to replace all the `R1C1` with `INDEX(C1:C1,MAX(1,ROW()-4))`

```
Range("C2:C7").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC1<>0,AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(C2:C2,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX(C1:C1,MAX(1,ROW()-4)):RC1)/(INDEX(C1:C1,MAX(1,ROW()-4)):RC1=1),3)):RC2,INDEX(C1:C1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX(C1:C1,MAX(1,ROW()-4)):RC1)/(INDEX(C1:C1,MAX(1,ROW()-4)):RC1=1),3)):RC1,1),0),0)"
```

Replace the `-4`s in the formula, there are 4 of them, with the limit of rows desired.

This does increase the count to 254 with a single digit limit of 4 rows.  If we go to the 11 it will go over the 255 you requested but, `.FormulaR1C1` does not have a character limit.

[image]

Comment: Interesting process and it seems to be working! A couple things; 1. Is there a way to modify it so it looks up a finite amount?  Like, for this example that the cells only look up 4 rows. ; 2. How does the aggregate work in an Index?  I'm not familiar with aggregate, but I am with Index Match.

Comment: As to the Aggregate, it returns the row number, finding the 3rd largest row number that has a 1 in column A between either row 1 or the desired number of rows up and the row in which the formula is placed. It then returns that row number to the INDEX which then returns that to the averageIFs

Comment: Absolutely perfect! You've helped me solve a problem I've had for months! Thank you thank you thank you!